# How to hide menu items in Kibana

Tags: kibana

I'm running Kibana 6.7.1 in Elastic Cloud. I'm open to upgrading it if will help.

I would like to hide all of the links (plugins? applications?) in Kibana's left navigation bar, except for "Discover", "Visualize", "Dashboard", and maybe "Canvas".  Ideally configured by space or by role.

I've read in a few places that Timelion can be disabled by setting `Timelion.enabled: false` in the `Kibana.yaml`. However, that setting is not [documented for 6.7](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.7/settings.html#settings).  And there are ten other links to hide.

Is this what [Application Roles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/6.7/defining-roles.html#roles-application-priv) are for? I did not get anywhere with trying to set them and I don't think they do this as I assume the documentation would list the roles for each default application if that was the case.

I've tried [Dashboard Only mode](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-dashboard-only-mode.html), but it's more restrictive than I would prefer.

Are there settings in Kibana to disable these links, or do I have to add CSS or use a proxy which edits the HTML to remove them?

Answer (score 3):

I am using the latest ELK stack **[ELK - 7.5.2]** to develop a custom plugin and have found following settings to be helpful in removing the clutter from Kibana.

You can add these to your ***kibana.yml*** file and set their values according to your needs:

```
xpack.canvas.enabled: false
xpack.reporting.enabled: false
xpack.actions.enabled: false
xpack.alerting.enabled: false
xpack.maps.enabled: false
xpack.security.enabled: false
xpack.uptime.enabled: false
xpack.watcher.enabled: false
xpack.spaces.enabled: false
xpack.license_management.enabled: false
xpack.upgrade_assistant.enabled: false
xpack.index_management.enabled: false
xpack.apm.enabled: false
xpack.beats.enabled: false
xpack.ccr.enabled: false
xpack.cloud.enabled: false
xpack.code.enabled: false
xpack.graph.enabled: false
xpack.grokdebugger.enabled: false
xpack.ilm.enabled: false
xpack.infra.enabled: false
xpack.logstash.enabled: false
xpack.ml.enabled: false
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
xpack.remote_clusters.enabled: false
xpack.rollup.enabled: false
xpack.searchprofiler.enabled: false
xpack.siem.enabled: false
xpack.snapshot_restore.enabled: false
xpack.tilemap.enabled: false
xpack.transform.enabled: false
```

Hope it helps.